# How to stop an activity from being closed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service

I am developing an alarm app which will stop after taking some input(images from camera) from user so I have created an activity(TActivity) which will launch when alarm triggers.

But when alarm triggers, the launched activity(TActivity) can be closed by user which will stop the alarm(**without going through the process of taking images from camera**) but I want to make my activity same as the default alarming app in android which stop only when user select either stop or snooze and can't be minimized or closed.

**Note: I have used AlarmManager, Service and Broadcast Receiver to make my alarm app work properly, the only problem is what I have mentioned below.**

OnCreate method of TActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_alarm_start);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    feeds = new ArrayList<>();
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewforD);

    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkPermissions();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Pic.jpg");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            startActivityForResult(intent,99);

        }
    });
}
```

> How to make my TActivity such that the user can't close it or minimize
>   it without going through the process of taking images from camera?